# Django: Can't pre-select from option menu Upon POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This has been taking over 7 hours with no success. By now I have no idea why.

I have two forms, [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3Mj.jpg) should give a pretty good indication of the flow I'm looking for.

So basically, a user either selects one of the existing items from the dropdown menu of BottleForm (marked in the screenshot as "1"), or he elects to click the Add button, which opens a modal of another form BrandForm (marked in the screenshot as "2"), which should let him fill a new brand name.

What I want is that when a new brand-name is submitted in the BrandForm and the page is reloaded, that brand is already pre-selected in the dropdown menu. I've read countless of threads but none of the suggested answers regarding setting `initial` on the field work.

Why is it not working?

**views.py (`add_brand` is the submit name for the BrandForm)**:

```
# Add brand form
        elif 'add_brand' in request.POST:
            brand_name = request.POST['name'] # this is the brand name we submitted
            context['form'] = BottleForm(initial={'brand': brand_name})
            context['form2'] = BrandForm(request.POST)
            the_biz = Business.objects.filter(owner=user.id).first()


            if context['form2'].is_valid():
                print("brand for valid!")
                brand = context['form2'].save(commit=False)
                brand.business = the_biz
                brand.save()
                return render(request, template_name="index.pug", context=context)
```

**bottle_form.pug:**

```
//- Create New Brand Modal
div.modal.fade.create-new-brand(tabindex="-1" role="dialog")
    div.modal-dialog.modal-sm(role="document")
        div.modal-content
            div.modal-header
                H3 Enter the Brand's name here:
            div.modal-body
                form.form-horizontal(method="post" action=".")
                    | {% csrf_token %}
                    | {{ form2.as_p }}
                    hr
                    btn.btn.btn-default(type="button" data-dismiss="modal") Close
                    input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit" value="submit")(name="add_brand") Add Brand
```

**models.py:**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="brands")

    permissions = (
        ('view_brand', 'View the brand'),
        ('del_brand', 'Can delete a brand'),
        ('change_brand', 'Can change a brand\'s name'),
        ('create_brand', 'Can create a brand'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Bottle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, default="")
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bottles")
    vintage = models.IntegerField('vintage', choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=750,
                                   validators=[MaxValueValidator(2000, message="Must be less than 2000")
                                    ,MinValueValidator(50, message="Must be more than 50")])

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=550, default="")

    @property
    def age(self):
        this_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
        return this_year - self.vintage


    permissions = (
        ('view_bottle', 'View the bottle'),
        ('del_bottle', 'Can delete a bottle'),
        ('change_bottle', 'Can change a bottle\'s name'),
        ('create_bottle', 'Can create a bottle'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.brand.name + " " + str(self.capacity) + " " + str(self.vintage)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if there's no slug, add it:
        if self.slug == "":
            self.slug = str(slugify(str(self.name)) + slugify(str(self.brand)) + str(self.vintage) + str(self.capacity))
        super(Bottle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If any more details are needed please let me know. This is driving me crazy.

BTW: I have no idea how Django is loading the options as a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `Brand` model has the `brand` field as a ForeignKey. This means that when you're passing `brand_name` as the initial value to `brand` in your `BottleForm`, it doesn't know what to do because it's expecting a ForeignKey, not a string. In this case, what you should do is when you add a new `brand_name`, you have to first create and save the `Brand` model instance, then get that instance you just saved, and then pass it to your `initial` parameter.

Here's some code to start off from:

```
elif 'add_brand' in request.POST:
    brand_name = request.POST['name'] # this is the brand name we submitted
    b = Brand(name=brand_name, business=...)  # you will have to figure out what Business object to set considering that is a ForeignKey.
                                              # Alternatively, you can define a default for your `business` field,
                                              # e.g. default=1, where 1 refers to the pk of that business object
    b.save()
    new_brand = Brand.objects.last()  # grabs the last Brand object that was saved
    context['form'] = BottleForm(initial={'brand': new_brand})
    ...  # rest of the magic here
```